# How to extract all the ranges and link content which have link from the RichEditBox in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

Imagine I have RichEditBox string length of 100 and have 10 links set to different sets from the string, now how to extract all the ranges of those 10 Links and the contents of the Links.
I have set the links for the RichEditBox in this way

```
RichEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.StartPosition = 10;
RichEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.EndPosition = 16;
RichEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.Link = "\"www.google.com\"";
```

Comment: I suspect the code you are using could only insert only one link for the text.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, use `TextGetOptions.FormatRtf` to get the text content in **Rtf** format.

Text -->"This is so[me sam](https://www.google.com)ple text", its Rtf format is as follows.

> {\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil
> Segoe UI Variable;}}\r\n{\colortbl
> ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;}\r\n{\*\generator
> Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 \r\n\pard\tx720\cf1\f0\fs21
> This is so{{\field{\*\fldinst{HYPERLINK
> "www.google.com"}}{\fldrslt{\ul\cf2 me sam}}}}\f0\fs21 ple
> text\par\r\n}\r\n\0

Then use regular expressions `(?<={HYPERLINK).*?(?=})` and `(?<=cf2).*?(?=})` to get the links and link content.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
       
        richEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "This is some sample text");
        richEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.StartPosition = 10;
        richEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.EndPosition = 16;
        richEditBox.TextDocument.Selection.Link = "\"www.google.com\"";
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string TextString = null;
        richEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out TextString);

        string pattern = @"(?<={HYPERLINK).*?(?=})";
        string input = TextString;

        int count=0;

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
           
            Debug.WriteLine("Link{0}: {1}",
                             ++count, match.Value.Trim());
        }

        
        count = 0;
        pattern = @"(?<=cf2).*?(?=})";

        richEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.NoHidden, out TextString);
       
        int searchStart = 0;
        int searchLength = TextString.Length;

        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Link Content{0}: {1} ",
                             ++count, match.Value.Trim());

            var searchText= TextString.Substring(searchStart, searchLength);

            pattern = @"("+match.Value.Trim()+")";
            foreach (Match posRes in Regex.Matches(searchText, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("startPos:{0} - endPos:{1} ",
                             posRes.Index, posRes.Index + match.Value.Trim().Length);
                searchStart = posRes.Index + match.Value.Trim().Length;
                searchLength = TextString.Length - posRes.Index - match.Value.Trim().Length;

            }
                
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the Start and End position of that Links content

Comment: I added some code in the second foreach, you can refer to it.